# Laravel Chunk Output

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, chunks

I have an array of products and I used Chunk in laravel , as the following to save these products , however , I want to add these products as Product Objects or at least get their id , how to do that

```
$recordChunks = array_chunk($records, parent::CHUNK_SIZE);

    foreach($recordChunks as $chunk) {          
        self::insert($chunk);
    }
```

Comment: To get id of each product in a chunck?

Comment: yes , or get each product as an instance of Product

Comment: May I know what you would do the product instance ...I don't understand why you need to get these ids or instance

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of products you want to insert and you want to get an array of the inserted IDs back?

Comment: yes I want to get the ids of the inserted products  to get them as objects later , to return them through the transformer ( in the transformer , I use many functions called on the object to do some calculation before sending it to the client server, these functions can't be called on array , they should be objects )